# Show current frame or display timecode (frames) on MPC-HC?

Tags: framerate, playback, keyboard-shortcut, video-player, time

Does anybody know if this is possible? I know how to encode timecode display using ffmpeg but I would like to avoid this step and find a way in MPC (currently my favorite video player). CTRL+J doesn't display this feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I landed here before finding the answer elsewhere (https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/307102-MPC-not-showing-frame-rate). Try View\Statistics (or Ctrl+4) to display the framerate, multiplier, and other statistics (w/o using a different filter).[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the video file has subtitles (even fake ones, even not being displayed), you can go to View -> Subresync (or hit Ctrl + 6) and you'll see the timecode in the status bar displayed as {Hour:Minute:second.frame}.  As yet, I haven't found how to make this display format permanent, to appear even without a subtitle track.

EDIT:  In my own searching, I just came upon a post elsewhere stating that if you right-click the time on the status bar, in ANY video, whether or not it has subtitles, then you will see an option for "High precision".  You only need to select it once, and then the preference will be remembered for all subsequent files (even audio only).

Comment: The "High precision" option shows milliseconds, but it doesn't show the frame number.

Answer (score 0):

Go to MPC settings, External filters, Add filter `ffdshow Video Decoder`. Move it to the top of the list and set it to `Prefer`.

Then double click it to open its settings. Check `OSD` (On-Screen-Display) then check `Current Frame`.

You can easily enable and disable to revert to your normal decoder by unchecking the box next to `ffdshow Video Decoder`

[image]

taken from this [forum](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/369080-Easiest-way-to-see-frame-numbers#post2363489)